# add class 'active' to current control

Tags: jquery

I use a simple jquery fade slider on my page

**HTML**

```
<ul id="slider1" class="images-list">
                        <li style="background-image: url('Content/img/bg_10.jpg')"></li>
                        <li style="background-image: url('Content/img/bg_11.jpg')"></li>
                        <li style="background-image: url('Content/img/bg_12.jpg')"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="controls">
                        <li class="active"></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $.fn.slider = function () {
    var $this = this;
    var $controls = $this.nextAll('.controls').first();
    var index;

    $this.find('li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $this.find('li:first-child').fadeOut('slow')
            .next('li').fadeIn('slow')
            .end().appendTo($this);

        $controls.find('li').removeClass('active');         
        index = $this.find('li:visible').index();
        $controls.find('li').eq(index).addClass('active');  
    },
    4000);
};
```

and I would like to add class 'active' to current control, but a position of a visible element in slider changes every time and it's the first element every time. How can I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/u9d3xa1q/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can utilize the [jquery.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [jquery.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) methods. Initially set the class to the first element in controls. And then:

```
//on next:
$controls.find('li.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');  
//on prev:
$controls.find('li.active').removeClass('active').prev('li').addClass('active');
```

Probably if you need an infinite sliding the above will need to change. Here is the code to match your current fiddle:

```
            if ($controls.find('li.active').next('li').length) {
            $controls.find('li.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $controls.find('li.active').removeClass('active').parent().find('li:first-child').addClass('active');
        }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzografski/9r231sjr/)

**Edit**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mzografski/9a24rdro/1/) is a fiddle with data attribute usage as per the comments.

Comment: You are welcome. It is possible to have a more elegant solution but that is what came to me in prima vista. You can also consider using some data- attributes to  work with like storing the slides real indexes.

Comment: Well, it's an interesting idea to use some data- attributes to keep indexes of slides.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a data attribute example as well.

Comment: Thank you, it's the same I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending element getting index and processing active based on that will result in problem and so  based on current item text which is visible we can set active in slider

http://jsfiddle.net/u9d3xa1q/14/

```
var index = $this.find('li:first').text();

            if(index == "11")
                index =0;
            else if (index == "22")
                index =1;
            else
                index =2;
            $controls.find('li').eq(index).addClass('active');
```

Comment: No, it's absolutely not a solution, because I can have any text in slides.